# Can't remove google.com from my Authorized domain list on OAUTH Consent Screen App verification console

Tags: google-chrome, google-oauth

So I have tried to verify my app for Google's OAUTH Consent Screen.
On the Prepare for verification section, It keeps popping up the missing domain google.com alert.
I do not depend on google.com and would actually prefer not to include it. Without including this I noticed I cannot submit the app for verification.
[image: Google OAUTH ERROR Image]

I included google.com and made the request for verification but my request got rejected for the reason "you need to remove domains that don't belong to you: google.com".
On the authorized domain list I delete google.com but it still pops up the red alert saying missing domain.
Is there somewhere else that I need to remove the dependency on Google.com on the GCP API and Services Section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authorized domains, is the domain name for your website, where you host your privacy policy and terms of service.  You need to verify this domain though google search console to verify that you own it.

You cant verify that you own google.com because you don't.

- [Authorized domains](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/production-readiness/brand-verification#authorized-domains)

[image]

Comment: Okay, I finally understand your answer, So my privacy policy domain url has an effect on the list of domains I have to verify. Because my privacy policy is a google doc on google.com is why it forces me to verify 'google.com'. I will be moving my privacy policy from the Google Docs I used to a page on my website. Thanks

Comment: Exactly Good luck 